# How can change icon color of EditText

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want change color of EditText Icon programmatically. Check my screenshot. I want icon take red color when input has error.https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih9tA.jpg . 
My xml code is

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:hint="@string/register_hint_name"
        android:labelFor="@+id/username_input_text"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username_input_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_user"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_user"
            android:drawablePadding="15dp"
            android:autofillHints="false"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

My Activity code is

```
if (username_text.isEmpty() || email_text.isEmpty() || password_text.isEmpty() || con_password_text.isEmpty()) {

                    layout_username.setError("The field Username is required!");
                    username_input_text.requestFocus();
}
```

My vektor code is

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="user_icon"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal">
  <path
      android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
      android:pathData="M12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.48,10 10,10 10,-4.48 10,-10S17.52,2 12,2zM12,5c1.66,0 3,1.34 3,3s-1.34,3 -3,3 -3,-1.34 -3,-3 1.34,-3 3,-3zM12,19.2c-2.5,0 -4.71,-1.28 -6,-3.22 0.03,-1.99 4,-3.08 6,-3.08 1.99,0 5.97,1.09 6,3.08 -1.29,1.94 -3.5,3.22 -6,3.22z"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: could you post the XML of the drawable itself?

Comment: @MahmoudOmara yes...i edit my post

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use TextInputEditText instead of the normal EditText

here's an example

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
   style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:boxStrokeErrorColor="@android:color/red"
            app:errorIconDrawable="@drawable/icon"
            app:errorTextColor="@android:color/white">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: man i want change color when my form submitted and this edittext has error

Comment: did not see that screenshot, this changes the entire question, give me 1min to edit my answer

Comment: and how this change?

Comment: i want help with code man...when i submit my form how can set and change the color

Comment: TextInputEditText has defined error properties where you can edit the colors and text

Comment: edited my answer again with the error text color and box color

Comment: it s not working..i want change icon...not box

Comment: you need to try exploring the properties on ur own, u shouldn't always come to stackoverflow wanting people to finish ur work for u, i edited the answer for the last time to include app:errorIconDrawable property, good luck